# How to use rich_text_area with simple_form in Ruby on Rails 6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, simple-form, ruby-on-rails-6, actiontext

At the moment simple_form does not support ruby on rails 6 action_text with the rich_text_area input field. 
So at the moment my input field can look like this in posts/_form.html.haml:

```
= f.label :description
= f.rich_text_area :description
= f.error :description, class: 'text-danger'
```

How to make it work as `= f.input :description` and have a rich text area?

Comment: Has been integrated with PR [#1646](https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form/pull/1646/commits/b5117ccd47ee73a970f6153b92cdca2b92c9e587)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

create a file in app/inputs/rich_text_area_input.rb:

```
class RichTextAreaInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::Base
  def input_html_classes
    super.push('trix-content')
  end

  def input(wrapper_options = nil)
    merged_input_options = merge_wrapper_options(input_html_options, wrapper_options)

    @builder.rich_text_area(attribute_name, merged_input_options)
  end
end
```

in application.scss:

```
//simple_form input for rich_text_area hight
trix-editor.form-control {
  height: auto;
}
```

Now in posts/_form.html.haml you can just do:

```
= f.input :description, as: :rich_text_area
```

Althrough hopefully at some point simple_form must add it to master

Source 1: https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form/issues/1638

Source 2: https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form/pull/1646

Comment: The first step (create a file in app/inputs/rich_text_area_input.rb) is not needed any more - it is already integrated into gem simple_form